# Redirect console.writeline from windows application to a string

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have an external dll written in C# and I studied from the assemblies documentation that it writes its debug messages to the Console using `Console.WriteLine`.

this DLL writes to console during my interaction with the UI of the Application, so i don't make DLL calls directly, but i would capture all console output , so i think i got to intialize in form load , then get that captured text later.

I would like to redirect all the output to a string variable.

I tried `Console.SetOut`, but its use to redirect to string is not easy.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As it seems like you want to catch the Console output in realtime, I figured out that you might create your own `TextWriter` implementation that fires an event whenever a `Write` or `WriteLine` happens on the `Console`.

The writer looks like this:

```
    public class ConsoleWriterEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Value { get; private set; }
        public ConsoleWriterEventArgs(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    public class ConsoleWriter : TextWriter
    {
        public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }

        public override void Write(string value)
        {
            if (WriteEvent != null) WriteEvent(this, new ConsoleWriterEventArgs(value));
            base.Write(value);
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string value)
        {
            if (WriteLineEvent != null) WriteLineEvent(this, new ConsoleWriterEventArgs(value));
            base.WriteLine(value);
        }

        public event EventHandler<ConsoleWriterEventArgs> WriteEvent;
        public event EventHandler<ConsoleWriterEventArgs> WriteLineEvent;
    }
```

If it's a WinForm app, you can setup the writer and consume its events in the Program.cs like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var consoleWriter = new ConsoleWriter())
        {
            consoleWriter.WriteEvent += consoleWriter_WriteEvent;
            consoleWriter.WriteLineEvent += consoleWriter_WriteLineEvent;

            Console.SetOut(consoleWriter);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    static void consoleWriter_WriteLineEvent(object sender, Program.ConsoleWriterEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Value, "WriteLine");
    }

    static void consoleWriter_WriteEvent(object sender, Program.ConsoleWriterEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Value, "Write");
    }
```

Comment: this DLL writes to console during my interaction with the UI of the Application, so i don't make DLL calls directly, but i would capture all console output , so i think i got to intialize in form load , then get that captured text later.

Comment: Is it a WinForms app? When in the program flow do you need the output?

Comment: yes it's a c# winform app , i need to capture console output after an GUI event.

Comment: i'm using RAPI library, i would like to get console output just after the RAPIDisconnected event , or during the application lifetime.

Comment: @geogeek: Answer modified. I wrote a simple class based on TextWriter that implements event handlers for Write and WriteLine that helps you to catch console output as it comes in.

Comment: i tested the code severale times , there's no errors , but there's no messagebox printing the console output , Thanks a lot @WouterH

Comment: Try to override other methods in the ConsoleWriter class like I did for Write and WriteLine

Comment: In order for this to work in your console app, you need to set Console.SetOut(new ConsoleWriter());

Comment: @DavidCFuchs do you mean the consolewriter that is already created cannot be passed to the SetOut like in my example? and you need to create a new, unused, instance?

Comment: @huysentruitw Not at all, I didn't see where you explained that SetOut() needs to be set. Adding the following two lines at the top of the console code section would resolve that .... ConsoleWriter passThis =  new ConsoleWriter();  ...  Console.SetOut(passThis);

Answer (score 22):

It basically amounts to the following:

```
var originalConsoleOut = Console.Out; // preserve the original stream
using(var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    Console.SetOut(writer);

    Console.WriteLine("some stuff"); // or make your DLL calls :)

    writer.Flush(); // when you're done, make sure everything is written out

    var myString = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}

Console.SetOut(originalConsoleOut); // restore Console.Out
```

So in your case you'd set this up before making calls to your third-party DLL.

Comment: this DLL writes to console during my interaction with the UI of the Application, so i don't make DLL calls directly, but i would capture all console output , so i think i got to intialize in form load , then get that captured text later.

Answer (score 4):

You can also call SetOut with Console.OpenStandardOutput, this will restore the original output stream:

```
Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can wrap it up in a helper method that takes some code as an argument run it and returns the string that was printed. Notice how we gracefully handle exceptions.

```
public string RunCodeReturnConsoleOut(Action code) 
{
  string result;
  var originalConsoleOut = Console.Out;
  try 
  {
    using (var writer = new StringWriter()) 
    {
      Console.SetOut(writer);
      code();
      writer.Flush();
      result = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
    return result;
  }
  finally 
  {
    Console.SetOut(originalConsoleOut); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using solutions proposed by [@Adam Lear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911660/redirect-console-writeline-from-windows-application-to-a-string/11911722#11911722) and [@Carlo V. Dango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911660/redirect-console-writeline-from-windows-application-to-a-string/12035524#12035524) I created a helper class:

```
public sealed class RedirectConsole : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action<string> logFunction;
    private readonly TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
    private readonly StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    public RedirectConsole(Action<string> logFunction)
    {
        this.logFunction = logFunction;
        Console.SetOut(sw);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.SetOut(oldOut);
        sw.Flush();
        logFunction(sw.ToString());
        sw.Dispose();
    }
}
```

which can be used in the following way:

```
public static void MyWrite(string str)
{
    // print console output to Log/Socket/File
}

public static void Main()
{
    using(var r = new RedirectConsole(MyWrite)) {
        Console.WriteLine("Message 1");
        Console.WriteLine("Message 2");
    }
    // After the using section is finished,
    // MyWrite will be called once with a string containing all messages,
    // which has been written during the using section,
    // separated by new line characters
}
```