# Getting output from .net assembly that calls Console.WriteLine

Tags: .net, powershell, output

I have a powershell script that loads a c# .net assembly and calls a method.
The method calls Console.WriteLine.
When I run the powershell script, the output doesn't show any of the information passed to Console.WriteLine, how can I get it to be output?

Ideally, I'd like the output to start appearing before the .net method returns.

I've seen this https://www.sapien.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=4514 is there a better solution?

Comment: You might want to *override* the behavior of `WriteLine()` like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911660/redirect-console-writeline-from-windows-application-to-a-string