# C# EventHandler to catch calling to Console.WriteLine() function

Tags: c#, console

I'm using [CefSharp.OffScreen (63.0.3)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen/) in my project.

This package sometimes prints messages to the console by calling `Console.WriteLine()`, there is a way to stop it by defining [`LogSeverity.Disable`](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/Enums/LogSeverity.cs) but they have an [open issue](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2427) of this bug (it's still printing).

I want, in my project, to catch any calls to `Console.WriteLine()` and decide whether to ignore it or print it.  Is there is a way to do that?

• Edit:

Any prints that came from the external package start with "[" symbol, So I just need to catch any print and check if the string starting with "[" to know if I want to print it or not...

Comment: I am not flagging as a dupe yet. Perhaps this question/answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911660/redirect-console-writeline-from-windows-application-to-a-string

Comment: you could redirect the console output.

Comment: if you redirect, you'll redirect all. this can be a solution if there is no other part of the application generating any console output you need. "decide whether to ignore it or print it": yes, but then it's all or nothing. there is no "source" in redirection which could be used for filtering (except maybe for adventurous approaches involving the current call stack)

Comment: If you start the console programm via Process, you can redirect all 3 I/O Streams. This is a baseline .NET Framework Process Function since 1.1 of the Framework (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx). The StreamReaders can then be polled. So I do not see why this remote operation framework would not allow it.